# cannot save MultipleChoiceField in django

Tags: django, save, multiplechoicefield

I am having problems saving a `MultipleChoiceField` on my test server (with Apache). However, it works on my local machine (django server).

In a form, I have `checkboxes` that I can check and uncheck. When I click on a save button, the data related to the checkboxes are saved in the database and the form is reloaded and the checkboxes updated.

However, this is how it works in local but not on the test server. On the test server, when I click on the save button, it just reloads the form, nothing is saved, nothing is changed.

Here is the code:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    databases = models.ManyToManyField(Advertiser, null=True, blank=True, through='ShareDataToBrands')

    @property
    def share_to_brands_list(self):
        brands=[]
        for brand in ShareDataToBrands.objects.all():
            brands.append((brand.advertiser.id, brand.advertiser.brand_name, brand.share_data))

        return brands

class ShareDataToBrandsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Participant
        fields = ('databases', )

    databases=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance=super(ShareDataToBrandsForm, self).save(commit=False)

        #list of brands to share data with
        share_list=map(int, self.cleaned_data.get("databases"))

        participant=self.instance
        for share_data_instance in models.ShareDataToBrands.objects.filter(participant=participant):
            if share_data_instance.advertiser.id in share_list:
                share_data=True
            else:
                share_data=False
            #update record
            share_data_instance.share_data=share_data
            share_data_instance.save()

        return instance
```

What could possibly be wrong?

---

**EDIT :**

When I check the `log`, I see that the program never enters in the `for loop`! However, I have records in the database matching the filter.

Comment: Dunno. You haven't told us what is happening.

Comment: This is not going to help people understand your problem, because your code should work if it works in your local environment. Have you tried to see where does the form data go to?

Comment: I just updated my post with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, looping through the`ShareDataToBrands` instances related to the participant instead of all the `ShareDataToBrands` instances.

In the `share_to_brands_list` property, have changed the following line:

```
for brand in ShareDataToBrands.objects.all():
```

with

```
for brand in ShareDataToBrands.objects.filter(participant=self):
```